# PHP strange is_int behaviour

Tags: php

I have a form which is posting an array which looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [SearchForm] => Array
    (
        [query] => Eg: 2 Bedroom Flat Chelsea
        [rent] => 1
        [share] => 0
        [short] => 1
        [price_min] => 50
        [price_max] => 100
    )

    [yt0] => Search
)
```

I want to check if the value for `$_REQUEST['SearchForm']['price_min']` is not empty, and is an integer. I am using:

```
if (($_REQUEST['SearchForm']['price_min'] != "") && (is_int($_REQUEST['SearchForm']['price_min']))){
    ...
}
```

The `is_int` is returning false (the if statement is not being executed)
Any ideas why?

Comment: `is_int` doesn't return true for strings, even if the string is numeric. `var_dump` the price_min and see if it's being saved as a string. If it is, use `ctype_digit` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because POST and GET parameters are always string, so instead of is_int use is_numeric

Comment: Cool danks. I didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

The value is probably `"50"` and not `50` (it's a string). Try `is_numeric()` instead of `is_int()`.

Answer (score 0):

If the result comes from a posted html form, the value is most likely a string.

You can use `is_numeric` to check for a valid number string.