# Username/ID Integer detection

Tags: php, parsing, types, casting

I am trying to detect if the input is a users id or a username. I've tried doing this

```
if (is_int($user)) {
    echo "is int";
}else{
    echo "is not";
}
```

However it isn't working, it doesn't detect it as an int if it is. I've thought about doing `(int) $user` but if they have a username like "example2" it will become 2 and then become the id 2 right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP strange is\_int behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460853/php-strange-is-int-behaviour)

Comment: What if the username is a number?

Comment: It will not become 2. It will become 0. "2example" would become 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

```
if(is_numeric($user)){
        echo "is int";
    }else{
        echo "is not";
    }
```

Comment: There _are_ numeric things other than integers.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check whether `$user` is *numeric*, you can use `is_numeric`. This can work depending on what kinds of usernames are allowed. For example:

```
is_numeric("+0123.45e6") === true
```

You can see some other examples in the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php#refsect1-function.is-numeric-examples).

If you really need to verify whether or not `$user` contains only numeric *characters*, you may want to use `ctype_digit` instead.

```
if (ctype_digit($user)){
    echo "is int";
} else {
    echo "is not";
}
```

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418461/php-best-way-to-check-if-input-is-a-valid-number) for some more possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
if(is_numeric($user)){
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: thanks @FrankerZ . Next time I will make sure that it is well commented before I post it.